# Symbol between two minipages with circuits

Tags: minipage, circuitikz

I would like to have a figure similar like this [image]
as far as I could get, this has been my humble attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
                \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{circuitikz}
                        \draw(0,0)
                        to[short,*-*](4,0)
                        ;
                        \draw(0,1.5)
                        to[short,*-](0.2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (3.8,1.5)
                        to[short,-*](4,1.5)
                        ;
                        \draw(2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,C=$ C_f $] (2,0)
                        ;   
                    \end{circuitikz}
                \end{minipage}%
                \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{circuitikz}
                        \draw(7.1,0)
                        to[short,*-*](5,0)
                        to[short,-*](4.5,0)
                        to[short,-*](2.5,0)
                        to[short,-*](2,0)
                        to[short,*-*](0,0)
                        ;
                        \draw(0,1.5)
                        to[short,*-](0.2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (2,1.5)
                        to[short,*-*](2.5,1.5)
                        to[short](4.5,1.5)
                        to[short,*-*](5,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (7,1.5)
                        to[short,-*](7.1,1.5)
                        ;
                        \draw(3.55,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,C=$ C_f $] (3.55,0)
                        ;
                        \draw[dashed](0.4,1.8)--(1.8,1.8);
                        \draw[dashed](0.4,1.8)--(0.4,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](0.4,-0.2)--(1.8,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](1.8,-0.2)--(1.8,1.8);
    
    
                        \draw[dashed](2.65,1.8)--(4.35,1.8);
                        \draw[dashed](2.65,1.8)--(2.65,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](2.65,-0.2)--(4.35,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](4.35,-0.2)--(4.35,1.8);
    
                        \draw[dashed](5.3,1.8)--(6.7,1.8);
                        \draw[dashed](5.3,1.8)--(5.3,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](5.3,-0.2)--(6.7,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](6.7,-0.2)--(6.7,1.8);
    
                    \end{circuitikz}
                \end{minipage}
                \caption{Example of ladder LC network as cascaded connection of two basic two-port networks.}
            \end{figure}
        \end{document}
```

Producting the following output[image]
As it can be seen, need that `<` `>` symbol in the middle. I have tried `raisebox` but it doesn't work, and I would appreciate if the figures in both minipages could be a bit closer from each other, as it is another thig that I struggle with when using minipages.

Thank you.

Comment: any news? now you have two answers ...

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need the minipages.  Circuitikz IS a tikzpicture.  Wouldn't `$\leftrightarrow$` be a better symbol?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
                    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                        \draw(0,0)
                        to[short,*-*](4,0)
                        ;
                        \draw(0,1.5)
                        to[short,*-](0.2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (3.8,1.5)
                        to[short,-*](4,1.5)
                        ;
                        \draw(2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,C=$ C_f $] (2,0)
                        ;   
                    \end{circuitikz}
\hfill $<>$ \hfill
                    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                        \draw(7.1,0)
                        to[short,*-*](5,0)
                        to[short,-*](4.5,0)
                        to[short,-*](2.5,0)
                        to[short,-*](2,0)
                        to[short,*-*](0,0)
                        ;
                        \draw(0,1.5)
                        to[short,*-](0.2,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (2,1.5)
                        to[short,*-*](2.5,1.5)
                        to[short](4.5,1.5)
                        to[short,*-*](5,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,L,l_=$ L_f $] (7,1.5)
                        to[short,-*](7.1,1.5)
                        ;
                        \draw(3.55,1.5)
                        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,C=$ C_f $] (3.55,0)
                        ;
                        \draw[dashed](0.4,1.8)--(1.8,1.8);
                        \draw[dashed](0.4,1.8)--(0.4,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](0.4,-0.2)--(1.8,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](1.8,-0.2)--(1.8,1.8);


                        \draw[dashed](2.65,1.8)--(4.35,1.8);
                        \draw[dashed](2.65,1.8)--(2.65,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](2.65,-0.2)--(4.35,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](4.35,-0.2)--(4.35,1.8);

                        \draw[dashed](5.3,1.8)--(6.7,1.8);
                        \draw[dashed](5.3,1.8)--(5.3,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](5.3,-0.2)--(6.7,-0.2);
                        \draw[dashed](6.7,-0.2)--(6.7,1.8);

                    \end{circuitikz}
                \caption{Example of ladder LC network as cascaded connection of two basic two-port networks.}
            \end{figure}
        \end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

as supplement to [John Kormylo's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo) answer (which solve op problem) focused on off-topic issues how to write circuits' codes shorter and concise:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
]
\draw   (0,1.5)     to [L,l_=$L_f$,*-] ++ (2.2,0)
                    to [L,l_=$L_f$,-*] ++ (2.2,0)
        (2.2,1.5)   to [C=$C_f$,*-*]   ++ (0,-1.5)
        (0,0)       to [short,*-*]        (4.4,0)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\hfill $\longleftrightarrow$ \hfill
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    box/.style = {draw, dashed, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=18mm},
                        ]
\draw   (0,1.5)     to [short,*-o]  ++ (0.2,0)
                    to [L,l_=$L_f$] ++ (1.8,0)
                    to [short,o-o]  ++ (0.4,0)
                    --              ++ (1.8,0)
                    to [short,o-o]  ++ (0.4,0)
                    to [L,l_=$L_f$] ++ (1.8,0)
                    to [short,o-*]  ++ (0.2,0)
        (3.3,1.5)   to [C=$C_f$,*-*]   ++ (0,-1.5)
        (0,0)       to [short,*-o]  ++ (0.2,0) -- ++ (1.8,0) 
                    to [short,o-o]  ++ (0.4,0) -- ++ (1.8,0)
                    to [short,o-o]  ++ (0.4,0) -- ++ (1.8,0)
                    to [short,o-*]  ++ (0.2,0)
        ;
\node[box]  at (1.1,0.8) {};
\node[box]  at (3.3,0.8) {};
\node[box]  at (5.5,0.8) {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]